# Why is this MySQL spatial query returning false rows?

Tags: mysql, spatial-query

I’m pulling rows based on the spatial value of column ‘latlng’, but I’m getting values outside the polygon being used by the query. For example one of the returned values is at 39.245231, -094.41976 almost 5 miles outside the polygon. Whats wrong with my query?

```
SELECT class, address, latitude, longitude, callsign,
               CONCAT(latitude,',',longitude) as koords,
               CONCAT(name,'<br>',address,'<br>',city,'<br>',latitude,', ',longitude) as addr,
               REPLACE(tactical,'-','') AS tactical
   FROM  poi
WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('POLYGON(( 39.6697989 -95.029305 , 39.6697989 -94.293333 , 38.899486 -94.293333 , 38.899486 -95.029305 , 39.6697989 -95.029305 ))'),latlng) 
      AND class = 'Sheriff'
 ORDER BY class
```

You can look at the map being produce at; https://net-control.us/map1Rose3.php once there click the ‘Police’ marker in the lower right to see the returned values. The map shows 4 blue flags marking the boundaries of the polygon, the red flag is the center. And two “P” markers that are outside the polygon.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MBRContains()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html#function_mbrcontains) is a minimum bounding rectangle function. It computes the [minimum bounding rectangle](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html) of its first parameter -- draws a box around it -- then checks whether the second parameter is inside that box.  It's designed to be cheap to  use in computer cycles and IO, but the tradeoff is that it picks up items that are in the MBR but outside the polygon.

Try [`ST_Contains()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains) instead.

Comment: I understood very little of what you recommend. What would my where clause have to look like to do what you say? I tried by setting $sg1 = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT("POLYGON((...my points...))"); but that just errors out.

Comment: I changed my query to use ST_CONTAINS() instead but now I get an error: FUNCTION ST_CONTAINES does not exist. As near as I can tell the syntax should be the same as using MBRContains().

Comment: Turns out I can't use ST_CONTAINS() because the version of MySQL I'm using is only 5.5 and apparently you need 5.6 or greater. But it is the correct answer.

Comment: If you're trying to to geospatial stuff and you're not on version 8+ you're probably wasting your time. MySql has made major advances since 5.5 came out at the end of **2010**.